# How to get all open file descriptors of the current process on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, file-descriptor

On Linux, I can get the current process's all open file descriptors by reading `/proc/self/fd`, but how I can get such info on FreeBSD?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the procstat(8) utility, in particular the "-f" option.

Comment: Command line may not work for me, I need such info in a program written by C++.

Comment: Just curious how `procstat -f` can get such info? Is there a system call for that? I guess there is no `/proc` filesystem on FreeBSD

Comment: The procstat(1) utility seems to be a wrapper around libprocstat(3), documented eg at https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=libprocstat&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12-current&arch=default&format=html

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can get such info by reading `/dev/fd`, see the manpage of `fdescfs` for more details.
https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fdescfs&sektion=5&manpath=freebsd-release-ports